# How to set the width of the sidebar in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 seems to have user settings for everything, but I cannot locate one to set the width of the sidebar.  I like it to be much narrower than it defaults to and am constantly manually setting it.

Anyone know where the setting is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I know enough that the sidebar width is per-project, i.e. stored in the `<project>.sublime-workspace` file.

The relevant keys are

```
"side_bar_visible": true,
"side_bar_width": 260.0,
```

So you could edit your workspace files with the width value you prefer.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try this, but I am going to leave this question open as I am looking for a user setting, not a per-project setting.  Of course, if there is no user setting for the sidebar width, than I will ultimately give you credit for the answer. :-)